# My T generic does implement the conditions on where, but I can't use it

Tags: rust

```
struct Response {}

struct PlayResponse(Response);
struct DescribeResponse(Response);

impl From<Response> for PlayResponse {
    fn from(response: Response) -> Self {
        PlayResponse(response)
    }
}

enum RtspState {
    Init,
    Playing,
}

struct RtspMachine {
    state: RtspState
}

pub trait OnEvent<T> {
    fn on_event(&mut self, event: &T) -> std::result::Result<(), ()>;
}

impl OnEvent<PlayResponse> for RtspMachine {
    fn on_event(&mut self, event: &PlayResponse) -> std::result::Result<(), ()> {
        self.state = RtspState::Playing;
        Ok(())
    }
}


fn do_something<T: OnEvent<T>>() where RtspMachine: OnEvent<T>, T: From<Response>{
    let mut rtsp_machine = RtspMachine{state: RtspState::Init};
    rtsp_machine.on_event(&T::from(Response{}));
    rtsp_machine.on_event(&PlayResponse::from(Response{}));
}
```

On the `do_something` above, we require  `where RtspMachine: OnEvent<T>, T: From<Response>`.

Note that `RtspMachine: OnEvent<PlayResponse>` and `PlayResponse: From<Response>`. I should be able to do `rtsp_machine.on_event(&PlayResponse::from(Response{}));`, but it only works for the version with `T`.:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:36:27
   |
33 | fn do_something<T: OnEvent<T>>() where RtspMachine: OnEvent<T>, T: From<Response>{
   |                 - this type parameter
...
36 |     rtsp_machine.on_event(&PlayResponse::from(Response{}));
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found struct `PlayResponse`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&T`
              found reference `&PlayResponse`
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6cbd2cb418e7ceb9fe2a533dbcad4160)

I know that

```
fn do_something<T>() where
    RtspMachine: OnEvent<T> + OnEvent<PlayResponse>,
    T: From<Response>
```

would work but I have lots of `T` that I wanted to use the specific type instead of generic `T`, so I can't just put them all on the `where` like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known problem with the compiler's method resolution in the presence of trait bounds ([#24066](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24066), [#38071](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/38071)). Changing your method call

```rust
    rtsp_machine.on_event(&PlayResponse::from(Response{}));
```

to the explicit function call form

```
    OnEvent::<PlayResponse>::on_event(
        &mut rtsp_machine, &PlayResponse::from(Response{}));
```

will allow the code to compile. Apparently, in the version that doesn't work, method resolution is looking only at the `OnEvent<T>` trait that's mentioned in `where`, even though `OnEvent<PlayResponse>` also exists.

I don't know if there's a more elegant solution, but perhaps the above will be adequate for your problem — at least it means the extra syntax is local to the call site.